# XML Parsing through internet in bada

Tags: libxml2, bada

I executed a code to get xml content from timesofindia but its not woking and the code which i used is

```
doc=xmlReadDoc(NULL,"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128936835.cms",NULL,0);
```

I am new to bada.Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadDoc
You have to first download the document and then pass it to xmlReadDoc as a null terminated string. The second parameter is like MihaiD said, the base url of your document.

To download the document first, see Osp::Net::Http API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you actually have to pass in the document as a string on that first parameter. The second parameter is just a base URL, used probably for converting some relative URLs in the document to absolute URLs.